# Mirroring object across global axis using mirror modifier?

Tags: modeling, modifiers, mirror

I'm having trouble mirroring an object across the global X axis. As it stands the mirror modifier uses the local object center.
Is there any way to use global axis as the pivot?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Set the *Mirror Object* to any object (e.g. `Empty`) placed at [0,0,0]  with no rotation.

[image]

Comment: I quickly misread that as "leave the mirror object empty". For anyone in my shoes, you will create a new Empty object on the scene which you set at 0,0,0 and then use that object as the Mirror Object.