# Why is X mirror not working on a mesh?

Tags: mesh, edit-mode, mirror

Does X-Axis Mirror work on a mesh?  I applied X-Axis Mirror to a set of bones and it worked but not on the mesh, I tried to mirror the mesh using the X-Axis Mirror option but it doesn't mirror anything.

Here's the [.Blend](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwnCnOOEcD5qOHRSbVVqQ0lOdk0/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: Could you explain your question in a bit more detail?

Comment: I tried to mirror the mesh using the X-Axis Mirror option but it doesn't mirror anything.

Answer (score 13):

The mesh isn't exactly symmetrical.

This behavior is intentional. Meshes which are *almost* (but not quite) symmetrical wont detect vertices as mirrored.
*This is needed to avoid problems with high-poly meshes where vertices may be very close.*

To resolve the problem, you can use the **Snap to Symmetry** tool.
See: *Mesh -> Snap to Symmetry*.

This has options to select a distance threshold and choose which side of the axis to use.

Answer (score 4):

This is because your mesh is not symmetrical.

*X mirror* looks for a corresponding vertex on the opposite side of the object's origin:

[image]
<sup>Grabbing the vertex at `1` will look for a vertex at `2`.</sup>

If your mesh is not symmetrical, chances are there is no vertex at `2`. If there's no corresponding vertex, then X mirror can't do anything.

Comment: What if I deleted half of the mesh?  Would it work?

Comment: @ChristopherMonday Yes, if you mirrored the remaining half back over to the other side, in order to provide X mirror with something to work off of.

Comment: @ gandalf3♦ It didn't work https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwnCnOOEcD5qbGJGZXphQU9LR1E/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @ChristopherMonday It's still asymmetrical. You need a symmetrical mesh with symmetrical topology for X mirror to work properly.

Comment: Looks symmetrical  now...https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwnCnOOEcD5qek1CVUxVWlZCeHc/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Looks like one side is still missing, so it's still not symmetrical.. Try mirroring the existing side to the other side (either with a mirror modifier or a destructive method, see http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/14634/599)

Comment: What about now?  https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwnCnOOEcD5qYlhJbzhpdkR3ZGM/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24978/discussion-between-christopher-monday-and-gandalf3).